# Insight about an example of a hyperbola in the projective space in my textbook

Tags: projective-geometry, quadratic-forms

I'm reading a text (https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/files/LectureNotes/Projective_geometry/Chapter_2_Quadrics.pdf) to study about Quadrics in the projective space. The following is the example (1) (on Page 26).

### Example

Consider the hyperbola $xy = 1$.
Using the homogeneous coordinate ($x = x_1/x_0, y = x_2/x_0$), we can transform into;
$$
\left( \frac{1}{2}(x_1 + x_2) \right)^2 - \left( \frac{1}{2}(x_1 - x_2) \right)^2 - x_0^2 = 0
$$

and then if (x_1 + x_2 \neq 0), we put

$$
y_1 = \frac{x_1 - x_2}{x_1 + x_2}, \quad y_2 = \frac{2x_0}{x_1 + x_2}
$$

and the conic intersects the copy of $\mathbb{R}^2 \subset P^2(\mathbb{R})$ (the complement of the line $x_1 + x_2 = 0$) in the circle;$y_1^2 + y_2^2 = 1$.

The original line at infinity $x_0 = 0$ meets this in $y_2 = 0$.

### Question

I understood that we transform the hyperbola ($x_1 x_2 - x^2_0 = 0$ in $P^2(\mathbb{R})$ into a circle in $\mathbb{R^2}$. But I can't quite imagine how $x_0$ and $y_2$ meet. Could someone help me understand this or give me some visual aid?

Comment: I'd say it should be $y_0=x_1+x_2,y_1=x_1-x_2,y_2=2x_0,$ making  $y_1^2 +y_2^2 = y_0^2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3-space it's a linear transformation taking one cone with singular point the origin to another, one with axis the $y=x$ in the $xy$ plane and the other the $z$-axis. However, the $x_0=1$ in one is $y_2=2$ in the other, and $y_0=1$ in the other is $x_1+x_2=1$ in the first. Only trouble is, one cone isn't right circular and the other is (i.e. the transformation is not just a rotation; there will be some stretching and contracting going on), so we get that $x_1+x_2=1$ intersects the cone $x_0^2=x_1x_2$ in a circle of radius $\frac{\sqrt3}2,$ and not $1.$ [image: circle]Similarly the cone $y_1^2+y_2^2=y_0^2$ intersects in $y_2=2$ to get a hyperbola, but not quite a rectangular one, like the one we started out with. [image: hyperbola]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and visual! for the second plot, it makes sense! But for the 1st plot, I have a couple of questions. (1) what are the blue planes (what you called `one` )...? (looks like y=1 and z=0?)  (2) at the end of the example (page 27 of https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/files/LectureNotes/Projective_geometry/Chapter_2_Quadrics.pdf ), there is a figure of circle with the intersection line, I tried to reproduce this based on your figure here (https://www.desmos.com/3d/96127eea25). The red cone and the green plane make a circle which is

Comment: (Cont.d) which is being cut in the middle by the orange z=0. does this look correct?

Comment: @Rowing0914 $z=0$ cuts through the cone point and I removed this $xy$-plane in both images, so no. In the first plot $x_1+x_2=1$ is represented by $x+y=1$ giving the circle (in blue), and $x_0=1$ by $z=1,$ giving $xy=1,$ not drawn, but you can sort of see the intersection anyway.

Comment: The [geogebra file](https://www.geogebra.org/m/trvkn9pv).

Comment: Thank you for your further reply and for sharing the geogebra project! Will look into it!